# Format OracleDataReader.GetDateTime to 'dd-MM-yyyy'

Tags: c#, datetime, oracle11g, odp.net

I'd like to format all of my dates to something like `dd-MM-yyyy` but can't seem to get it to work.  All of the columns below that use `OracleDataReader.GetDateTime` are `DATE` fields in the DB.

```
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   myDetails detail = new myDetails();
   detail.ColumnA = reader.GetDecimal(0);
   detail.ColumnB = reader.GetString(1);
   detail.ColumnC = reader.GetDecimal(2);
   detail.ColumnD = reader.GetDateTime(3);
   detail.ColumnE = reader.GetDecimal(4);
   detail.ColumnF = reader.GetDateTime(5);
   detail.ColumnG = reader.GetDateTime(6);
   detail.ColumnH = Convert.ToChar(reader.GetString(7));
   detail.ColumnI = reader.GetDateTime(8);
   details.Add(detail);
}
reader.Close();
```

I've tried the following but each give me errors:

```
detail.ColumnD = reader.GetDateTime(3).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy');
detail.ColumnD = reader.GetDateTime(3).Parse('dd-MM-yyyy');
detail.ColumnD = reader.GetDateTime(3).TryParse('dd-MM-yyyy');
detail.ColumnD = DateTime.Parse(3).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy');
detail.ColumnD = reader.GetDateTime(3).ToLongDateString('dd-MM-yyyy');
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What is the type of ColumnD?

Comment: And this is the problem. You can't store a string in a datatime variable. You keep it as datetime and, only when needed to show on video or print, apply the formatting required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`detail.ColumnD` is probably a `DateTime` type. `DateTime` has no format. You format a `DateTime` when you convert it to a string. So after you've done:

```
detail.ColumnD = reader.GetDateTime(8);
```

Do:

```
Console.WriteLine("ColumnD: "+detail.columnD.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

This will allow you to see the difference. So anywhere you want to actually display `detail.ColumnD` in the UI, convert it to a string and pass in the necessary format string. For example, see below.

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;
TextBox tb=new TextBox();
tb.Text=dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

For those that find this question via a web search, you can change the date format to any other valid format string. There are several pre-defined ones or you can do custom ones. See [Custom Date And Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in MSDN Documentation.

For a deeper understanding, the DateTime object actually just stores the number of ticks (100 nanosecond units) since midnight on January 1st of 0001 Common Era. DateTime has convenience methods that understand how to convert from a string (Parse or TryParse) or to a string. See [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation in MSDN for more details.

Comment: Yes, formatting only applies when some value is converted to a string representation.